# Jaspersoft server and ireport designer

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am new to *JasperReports* and I'm working with *iReport* designer.

I have a html 5 pie chart, my query is on click of a chart i should be redirected to other report or other chart. I got a solution using hyperlink in jrxml but i want to do the same in *iReport* designer. I am totally stuck with this.

Also i need to deploy this on *JasperReports Server*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JasperReport Server supports this with a Hyperlink type of ReportExecution. You have to pass in a parameter named "_report" with a string value of the location and name of the report.

Here is an example on the Jaspersoft Community site: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/817802/using-hyperlink-type-reportexecution-jasperserver